# Can a Chrome Extension UI panel be set freely in its size and position?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[image: 1]

Hello, I am a design student working on a proposal of Chrome extension- wondering if it's possible to create a window panel that looks like the attached image.

In my plan, ➊ the panel would be positioned at the bottom right of the screen.
And it'll be also nice if it can be ➋ scrollable, ➌ have a floating button with shrinkable feature (like Grammarly), and ➍ and have a responsive color palette to the content (maybe the meta tags of the link?). Do you think it's feasible? Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You must be on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions.

Comment: It's possible by adding a DOM element in the content script e.g. an iframe that points to an html file in your extension exposed via web_accessible_resources. The position of the iframe can be specified via CSS `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`.